# Install jenkins on windows 10 error - Running with Java class version 53.0, but 52.0

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to install jenkins on a windows 10 machine that originally only had java 9 installed.

When i try to run the command: java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
I get: SEVERE: Running with Java class version 53.0, but 52.0 is required.

So, after research I found I needed Java 8.

I've downloaded java 8 jdk.

How do I point the jenkins install to the java 8 if the java 8 jdk is at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181?

Does it matter if I'm running commands in powershell? Do the commands there differ from cmd.exe?

Comment: Just ensure your PATH variable is pointing to the JDK 8 installation path and re-run your command

Answer (score 1):

The command that was successful in powershell was:
& "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081